# Internet Explorer 7.0 - force open office docs (XLS, PPT etc) - in browser window

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ms-office

using:  XP, IE 7.0,  Office 2010, working within a company INTRAnet

HomePage created in Word & saved as html, with links to other Office files

I want these office files to open within the browser frame, but no matter what I try (including the target frame settings in MS word..edit hyperlinks) the files launch into new Excel, Powerpoint, or Word windows.  Any way to fix this ?

fyi ...

I achieved the desired behavior on my personal machine by setting WindowsExplorer==>FolderOptions==>Advanced==> (pick XLS) ==> check "Browse in Same Window", but I can't control that setting on other users' machines.  I can fiddle with the HTML and insert VBA if nec, but am not in control of user settings/registry settings.

Comment: Are you actually saving them as `.html` files?

Comment: no, the start page is html & url's directly reference *.xls, *.ppt etc. office files

Comment: IE9 on XP, really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, a few bits of information:

1. IE9 is not and will not be released for Windows XP, so your specifications must be wrong
2. Office documents are not web-compatible file types, they will not open up in a browser
3. If you wish to provide Office documents via an intranet, they will either have to be:

   a. Downloaded and opened in the appropriate Office program

   b. Accessed using [Office Web Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Apps)

   c. Similarly setup files on [Google Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs)

   d. Setup a [SharePoint Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Server)

   e. Converted to PDFs or HTML form

Comment: Point #2 isn't actually correct. Internet Explorer is actually a DocObject Host; HTML is only one of the document objects that it can host. Depending on what version of Office you have installed, you may also have Office DocObjects that will show those files. However, that form of hosting is deprecated now, and it won't work if the site in question is running in Protected Mode.

Comment: The spec was wrong - I corrected it to IE 7.0.  I actually am doing this via a Sharepoint server.  I simply want the behavior to have the "look and feel" of a browser rather than an office app, even though this is admittedly a "cheat".  I know it's possible since it works when I change the windows explorer settings as described above, I just want to know if it's possible via some setting in the office doc, the HTML of the office doc, or some programmable setting not typ[ically requiring admin rights.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT: What I meant was native support, yes, it would open up encapsulated applications - but you still need the application installed.  It is opening it in the application, just displaying within a host window.  As you say, deprecated now.

Comment: Eric - thanks - accepted answer, but.. I'm not tring to build HTML pages via office, but simply distribute Office files to office users via Intranet rather than shared drive, email, server replication. This is for a bank w multiple locations, servers, IT depts (messy). Just save to Sharepoint, and everyone everywhere can view. Everything works ... I just want that one last setting to force IE to open the sheet within the IE window (better cosmetics, look & feel), and not open a separate office window. I can live without this, but if you have one last piece of advice I'll take it. Thanks

Comment: @tpascale: If you look on the internet for this problem, you'll see almost every thing is how to do the opposite, force opening in the application, not IE.  A lot of the answers tend to suggest using the `Content-Disposition` on the download set to `attachment`, maybe using `inline` on the disposition will help.  Though from what I can see, IE is setup for security to ask what they want to do with the file, a registry setting can be set for permanent opening in IE.  Maybe you can get the network administrator to roll out the registry change to all the intranet.